# List of free online brewing books and guides

Tags: books

There are some well known [actual books](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/89/book-for-beginners) like [John Palmer's How to Brew](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0937381888) (which, actually, happens to be [freely available online](http://howtobrew.com/)).

What other books and guides are available for free online that teach homebrewing?

Comment: Are there others?  I guess it comes down to what you define as a guide, as many other forums, blogs and personal web sites have tons of info available.  Too much to probably list.

Comment: Could be a good question to turn in to a community wiki, like http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/784/what-software-do-most-brewers-use, so we can get a good list going

Comment: I agree, this is one that would be good for the wiki.

Comment: Keep in mind that only the 1st edition of HTB is available online.  In print, it's up to the 3rd edition, which is much improved and expanded over what's available online.

Comment: True, "guide" is a little general, but there aren't that many books so I had to make things a bit more broad. I agree this would be a good Community Wiki page.

Answer (score 2):

There's [Brau Kaiser's wiki](http://braukaiser.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and the [Home Brewing Wiki](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which are both large and detailed, though maybe not as easy to use as Palmer's book.

Answer (score 2):

[Brew Your Own (byo.com)](http://byo.com) has some great articles and resources, like hop charts, grain charts, etc.